# Blood magic in a science fantasy?

Tags: magic, nanotechnology, blood

I'm putting together a story that centers around a unified galactic government, but I hit a small snag. Blood magic would be the only "supernatural" aspect of the story, and it would be illegal to perform due to its possibly dangerous uses. The way one would perform the magic would be to either use your own blood, or someone else's, and draw a rune on either yourself or your target. Different runes would have different effects.

Anyway! I'm having issues finding a reasonable way to implement this. I would rather forego the easy option of having a god or some unseen force in the background that hand waves the magic into motion. Would nano machines in the blood be a viable option? Using what we would call "gestures" on our current touchscreen devices as the premise for the runes?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Naphtali, this is an interesting question. Effectively you have already answered it yourself. Yes nanotechnology in the blood & a system of "gestures" for the control interface. The shape of the different runes could be part of a graphical interface (sort of). So yes you have devised your onw naturalistic explanation for apparently "supernatural blood magic". Have fun!

Comment: It's your magic system. You get to describe how it works. If you want it to work with nano-machines in the blood, then it works with nano-machines in the blood

Comment: What are some of the things you want your blood magic capable of doing?  Its capabilities would influence its implementation.  Also some things might be too extreme to come up with a scientific way of explaining the magic.

Comment: Thanks everyone, these comments and suggestions were super helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go the midichlorians route (sorry for prequel reference). Idea being that some ancient civilization genetically engineered people with this blood magic ability as you described. That civilization collapsed and after a new one was built in the millennia that followed, the the use of this baked in ability was outlawed.

You could also go the route of an infectious nano-tech "disease" being responsible for the blood magic. In this case the source doesn't have to be an ancient galactic civilization. It could be something that the current galactic civilization spread by accident, or something that they encountered as part of their expansion and then inadvertently spread throughout the galaxy (despite their best efforts to contain it).

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to define what will your Blood Magic will be able to do, how is it different from using technology.

I'm guessing that your setting will have supernatural elements, since well, there's magic.

You need to realize that in the end it will depend on what is your choice. Having said that, since you're asking for what would be other options, I propose this one, and you can build from here:

- Lets say that there's a magic particle, but it isn't physical in nature. This means that it doesn't interact with physical things, with the exception of Blood. Blood is what brings this particle into the physical world. So, with a combination of Blood, Focus and a desire to cause an effect, you can do magic.
- How this would work? well, while the magic particle stays as a non-physical particle, it ignores the mind, but once it gains a physical body in the Blood, the magic particle can't ignore the mind, and acts accordingly to the mind desires. It also happens that this magic particle is the beginning of every physical existence, and that is why it so versatile, from turning into a fireball to, dunno, letting you skip evolution by some steps and grant you wings.

There is a possible way. Take it, ponder it, change it accordingly to your needs. Hope it helps.